# Lua table.insert - strange behaviour when inserting to table

Tags: lua, lua-table

I'm having a bit of a hard time figuring out why my code is behaving the way it is. I have a table named players, structured as key, value pairs. The values are also nested tables (items). Each item, should contain at least one unique identifier, named 'id', contained withing the nested table (key name) 'specs'.

```lua
players = {

  ['identifier_one'] = {
    {
      ["label"] = "Flashlight",
      ["weight"] = 1,
      ["name"] = "WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT",
      ["specs"] =  {
        ["pockets"] = false,
        ["id"] = "ZT345", --This is our unique identifier
        ["equip"] = true,
        ["stack"] = 1,
        ["craft"] = true
      }
    },
    {
      ["label"] = "Flashlight",
      ["weight"] = 1,
      ["name"] = "WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT",
      ["specs"] =  {
        ["pockets"] = false,
        ["id"] = "ACF124",
        ["equip"] = true,
        ["stack"] = 1,
        ["craft"] = true
      }
    }
  },

  ['another_item'] = {
    ...
  },
}
```

I've got the data structure writing correctly. However, when I insert a new nested item, it's adding the newItem to the next increment within the table as expected, and at the same time it's overwriting all of the previus indexes. So the previous items ['spec']['id'] becomes the newItem id if that makes sense? So looking at the above layout, the previous id 'ZT345' would become 'ACF124'. Thus making the two items identical.

When I print out what the newItem consists off, everything is perfect and should write to the table as intended. At first, I thought it may have been something related to the encoding the table into json when writing to the database. However, if I print out the players[identifier] table, after inserting the newItem, it has then overwritten all previous indexes. So I'm pretty certain the issue is upon inserting the newItem to my players[identifier]

My code is as follows:

```lua
ESX.RegisterServerCallback('zombie-inventory:itemCheck', function(source, cb, item)

  --check our item is allowed to be added.
  if items[item] then

    local src = source
    local identifier = getIdentifier(src)
    local newItem = items[item]

    if string.match(item, 'WEAPON') then
      newItem['specs'][1].id = genId(players[identifier])
    end

    --This point is where the code falls apart.
    table.insert(players[identifier], newItem)

    MySQL.Async.execute('UPDATE `user_inventory` SET `inventory` = @inventory WHERE `identifier` = @identifier', {
      ['@identifier'] = identifier,
      ['@inventory'] = json.encode(players[identifier])
    })

    cb(true)
  else
    print(('[inventory] [^3WARNING^7] invalid item for itemCheck cb: %s'):format(item))
  end
end)
```

Just to add, the genId() function is 100% returning a unique id, I've printed the id numerous times, and it's always different.

Comment: Why do you write `newItem['specs'][1].id` instead of `newItem['specs'].id`?

Comment: The data is stored in a database as json, so when I pull it, I decode it from json into lua tables. The library I use, if it see's a nested list [], then it creates that as a nested table in lua as non key, value. So in this scenarion, specs = { 1 = {our data} } just without the 1 =

Comment: if you know you key is unique why use insert? Why not just assign the value to the table index?

Comment: Yeah that fixed it, cheers :) 
```lua
  "LL838": {
    "label": "Flashlight",
    "name": "WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT",
    "weight": 1,
    "specs": {
      "equip": true,
      "craft": true,
      "stack": 1,
      "pockets": false
    }
  },
  "JE275": {
    "label": "Flashlight",
    "name": "WEAPON_FLASHLIGHT",
    "weight": 1,
    "specs": {
      "equip": true,
      "craft": true,
      "stack": 1,
      "pockets": false
    }
  }
```